# Is $1 \otimes 1$ always the unity element in a tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $C$ and $D$ be $B$ algebras, where $B$ is a commutative ring with unity. 
And consider $C \otimes_B D$?

I first thought $1 \otimes 1$ was always the unity element in tensor products, 
but then I saw examples where $1 \otimes 1$ is in fact $0$. 
I thought perhaps the following is true?: 
$1 \otimes 1$ is the unity element in $C \otimes_B D$ if and only if $C \otimes_B D \not =  \{ 0 \}$

Comment: In the zero ring the unique element is a unit for multiplication, so you don't need to exclude this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $1\otimes1$ is the unity in the tensor product algebra, because it satisfies
$$
(1\otimes1)(c\otimes d)=c\otimes d=(c\otimes d)(1\otimes1)
$$
so the property also transfers to every element of $C\otimes_BD$.

If it happens that $1\otimes1=0$, then you can conclude that $C\otimes_BD=\{0\}$.

The ring $\{0\}$ as a unity, namely $0$. There is no requirement that in a ring the unity (identity) is nonzero.

The condition $1\ne0$ is imposed to domains (and so to fields), because there are very good reasons not to consider $\{0\}$ a domain.